# Prevent PHP from transforming links transparently in the response

Tags: php

In my PHP response I am setting the header "Content-type: application/binary" but that is not stopping PHP from rewriting my response.

How do I prevent PHP from transparently transforming the response to insert the PHPSESSID when the use_trans_sid has been enabled by my webhost? Is it possible to do this without using ini_set or modifying the htaccess file?

Comment: why the "without using ini_set" restriction?

Comment: Are you sure PHP is making the transformation?  Maybe it is the browser using an incorrect application association.

Comment: @wallyk: How can the browser's interpretation of the response from the server _change_ what that response was?

Comment: @fab Because some webhosts do seem to disallow ini_set.

Comment: @wallyk Yes. I am sure that PHP is doing the transformation.

Comment: I think you should talk to your webhost. They have disabled a feature, on _their_ servers. They probably have a reason. Discuss it with them instead of trying to hack around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never tried, but according to the documentation, [output_reset_rewrite_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.output-reset-rewrite-vars.php) does the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) is where you can change INI settings. `session.use_trans_sid` has a mode of PHP_INI_ALL, that leaves you with

1. ini_set()
2. php.ini
3. .htaccess
4. .user.ini
5. httpd.conf

Edit: disregard this, today I learned about `output_reset_rewrite_vars`